# Spring MVC: How to get context param when instantiate the bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

this is simple question,

how to get servlet context parameter when spring instantiate the bean?

my servlet context xml

```
<beans:bean id="ApplicationInfo" class="xx.xx.xx.ApplicationInfo"/>
```

In my code

```
public class ApplicationInfo{
   ApplicationInfo()
   {
      //get context.xml or web.xml parameter
      String xxx = .......;
   }
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<org.springframework-version>3.2.11.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
<org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
<org.springsecurity-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
<org.springjpa-version>1.1.0.RELEASE</org.springjpa-version>
<hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
<postgresql.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
<tiles-version>2.2.2</tiles-version>
<jackson-json-version>2.1.0</jackson-json-version>
```

Note: i tried to get servlet context by using @annotation ,however it is nullpointer.

[image]

Comment: Don't. Inject the `Environment` and manually retrieve the value using `getProperty` or simply add a field annotated with `@Value("${your.property.name}")` this will inject the property. The `ServletContext` is one of the consulted resources for properties.

Comment: How to inject the Enviroment ? or maybe some link for me to study?

Comment: Just add `@Autowired` on a field of the type `Environment`. Also note that it is available AFTER construction, trying to access it in the constructor will fail. Using the `Environment` gives you an abstraction for the properties and allows you to (for instance) put them in properties file or JNDI or the web.xml (or you can mix). And it cleans your code from being tied to the servlet context.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your help! the @ value does not work(show me null),however Maciej Walkowiak has solved my problems.Very appreciate for your help and taught me somethings.

Comment: Hmm strange as it should work, I assume you have a `context:annotation-config` and `context:property-placeholder`, the latter doesn't need a location to load properties from. I would really suggest using the `Environment` instead of the `ServletContext` as that basically ties your bean to the web and I assume you want to use it else where in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access autowired bean in constructor, you have to use constructor type injection:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationInfo {
    private final FooService fooService;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationInfo(ServletContext servletContext, FooService fooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;

        // do something here
    }
}
```

If you have to (or want to) stick to XML beans definition you've got to make your class implement [ServletContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) interface, which makes Spring automatically set this dependency through setter. Instead of accessing it in constructor, you do it in method annotated with [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) which is fired when bean is fully initialized:

```
public class ApplicationInfo implements ServletContextAware {
    private final FooService fooService;
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public ApplicationInfo(FooService fooService) {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // now you fooService and servletContext are set
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

```
<bean class="demo.ApplicationInfo">
    <constructor-arg name="fooService" ref="fooService" />
</bean>

<bean id="fooService" class="demo.FooService"/>
```

Comment: Its work! however, if my bean have some parameter need to inject it , then how?
like <bean id="knight" class="com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight">
<constructor-arg ref="quest" />
</bean>

Comment: I've updated the answer, I think it answers fully to your problem now

Comment: Thanks @Maciej Walkowiak! your solution solve my needs now. i have a additional question base on this solution. Assume the applicaiontInfo is Bean A, someServices is Bean B. Bean B instantiate from the constructor and inject Bean A (example: <constructor-arg name="BeanA" ref="Bean A" />). So my ordering is  instantiate Bean A with servlet context(in order to get some value from context.xml), then instantiate Bean B. will your solution able to make Bean A already collect info before inject into Bean B? i will try this scenario after this comment posted.

Comment: from my above scenario, the ordering is: Bean A constructor, then Bean A @postconstruct init(), then Bean B constructor. fully answer my question! thanks a lot and appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@Value` annotation

```
public class ApplicationInfo {
   @Value("${parameterName}")
   private String parameter;
}
```